# LinkedIn:Media posts not visible on wall after sharing using REST API

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I am trying to create a PHP script which shares posts on LinkedIn automatically with the help of zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client SDK https://github.com/zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client. I could share a post without any media and it is visible on my LinkedIn wall. When trying to share a post with an image, the API response returned true with an id  **urn:li:share:6605357601301553152**, but the post is not visible on my wall. I am providing my code for posting media below.

```
public function postMedia($data,$accessToken){
    try{
        $mediareturn = $this->client->post(
            'assets?action=registerUpload',
            [
                "registerUploadRequest"=>[
                    "recipes"=> [
                        "urn:li:digitalmediaRecipe:feedshare-image"
                    ],
                    "owner"=> "urn:li:person:**********",
                    "serviceRelationships"=> [
                        [
                            "relationshipType"=> "OWNER",
                            "identifier"=> "urn:li:userGeneratedContent"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );
        $uploadUrl = $mediareturn['value']['uploadMechanism']['com.linkedin.digitalmedia.uploading.MediaUploadHttpRequest']['uploadUrl'];

        $filepath = $this->root_url.'assets/uploads/'.$data['attachment'];

        $shell = shell_exec('curl -i --upload-file '.$filepath.' --header "Authorization: Bearer "'.$accessToken.' '.$uploadUrl);

        $share = $this->client->post(
            'ugcPosts',
            [
                "author"=> "urn:li:person:**********",
                "lifecycleState"=> "PUBLISHED",
                "specificContent"=> [
                    "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent"=> [
                        "shareCommentary"=> [
                            "text"=> $data['content']
                        ],
                        "shareMediaCategory"=> 'IMAGE',
                        "media"=> [
                            [
                                "status"=> "READY",
                                "description"=> [
                                    "text"=> "Center stage!"
                                ],
                                "media"=> $mediareturn['value']['asset'],
                                "title"=> [
                                    "text"=> "Test posting"
                                ],
                                "thumbnails"=> [],
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                    ],
                "visibility"=> [
                    "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility"=> "PUBLIC"
                ]
            ]
        );
        return $share;
    }catch(Exception $e){
        throw $e;
    }

}
```

The above code was written referring the official document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin.
Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am also facing exact same problem. Do share the codes if possible.